# Migrate error after add new field use django-pgcrypto-fields

Tags: python, django, migrate, pgcrypto

Migrate error after add new field use django-pgcrypto-fields

My model (migrate okay in the first time)

```py
class Dkm(models.Model):
    name = fields.TextPGPSymmetricKeyField()
    value = fields.IntegerPGPSymmetricKeyField(default=0)
```

I update model and migrate again:

```py
class Dkm(models.Model):
    name = fields.TextPGPSymmetricKeyField()
    value = fields.IntegerPGPSymmetricKeyField(default=0)
    value3 = fields.IntegerPGPSymmetricKeyField(default=0)
```

Error occur

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\vu.tran\Desktop\kona-server\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\vu.tran\Desktop\kona-server\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\vu.tran\Desktop\kona-server\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\vu.tran\Desktop\kona-server\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\vu.tran\Desktop\kona-server\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\vu.tran\Desktop\kona-server\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\vu.tran\Desktop\kona-server\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\vu.tran\Desktop\kona-server\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\vu.tran\Desktop\kona-server\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\vu.tran\Desktop\kona-server\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "value3" is of type bytea but default expression is of type integer
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

The error will not occur if set null=True

Comment: column "value3" is of type bytea but default expression is of type integer.  value3 Where?

Comment: @RustamPulatov oh, I edited value2 to value3, and migrate again but still that error.

Answer (score 0):

The error

> column "value3" is of type bytea but default expression is of type integer

refers to the `default=0` thing in your fields definition.

And the reason that it appears only while the second time you migrate with added field `value3`  is because it would be actually looking for the default values for already existing records. Whereas there doesn't exist any record for the first time you migrate.